# Is there anyway to turn a Drawable to an int in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-resources

I am making an app that displays the details of the Android device's installed permissions. Currently, I am displaying an AlertDialog with the icon for said permission but I would also like to deliver a notification as per the user's request. My code is:

```
Drawable icon;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String permission = getArguments().getString("permission");
    String label = "";
    String description = "";
    icon = null;
    try {
        label = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).loadLabel(getActivity().getPackageManager()).toString();
        description = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).loadDescription(getActivity().getPackageManager()).toString();
        icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).loadIcon(getActivity().getPackageManager());
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Permission")
            .setMessage("Permission: " + getArguments().getString("permission") + Character.toString((char) 10) + "Label: " + label + Character.toString((char) 10) + "Description: " + description)
            .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", null)
            .setCancelable(false);
    if (icon != null) {
        builder.setIcon(icon);
    }
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // Show notification here
        }
    });
    return alertDialog;
}
```

However, the v4 NotificationCompat.Builder can not take a Drawable only an int, so what should I do?

Comment: `the v4 NotificationCompat.Builder can not take a Drawable only an int`. It takes the **resource id**. Which turns out to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the icon resource id like that (assuming that `permission` is the String that you also use in your question):

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PermissionInfo info = pm.getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
int iconResourceId = info.icon;
```

And then...

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setSmallIcon(iconResourceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

R.drawable is an integer and so is R.color or R.string or R.layout